# Why does Erlang run configuration in Eclipse IDE stop at 57%?

Tags: erlang, erlide

I am starting out Erlang in Win 7 64 bit box and I was able to use Erlang IDE just fine and since I am used to Eclipse I wanted to use Erlide with Eclipse. I am following [running project document on erlide](http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html#running_project) I was able to follow along. (Except step 41, Where it is talking about adding something to 'Main tab' and in my case it shows as 'Erlang', but options they are same) When I run the 'new configuration' on the HelloWorld example it runs and stuck at 57%.

- I did install Erlang on my PC and installed it in a directory without space and it does shows up on my installed runtime in Eclipse.
- When I run I do not see 'Eclipse IDE' like I saw when I was running Scala IDE in eclipse.
- I did enter a dummy cookie name just in case if that is the problem
- I tried running 'erl -name foo' to make sure node is able to run and it did.

Is there anything I need to check?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first this:
* delete the configuration you created
* open a file in your project, right-click in it and choose Run as -> Erlang application

This will create a configuration that should work. You should see a console opening, where you can interact with the Erlang node.

If that is not happening, please go to window->preferences->erlang->report problem and create a report. Attach it to an issue at https://github.com/erlide/erlide/issues or send it to erlide_bugs@lists.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Win 7 - 64bit.

1. Problem: After some very first times build and run successfully, then eclipse couldnt run anymore. Restart Eclipse won't help.
2. Solution: Restarting the computer, and plz remember to Build Project before running it.